# Writing an equation for a hyperbola that has specific x- and y-intercepts

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

I know the question sounds weird, they're not supposed to have intercepted.

I'm trying to create a hyperbolic equation for an algorithm that has a y-intercept of $50$ and an x-intercept of $100$. I'm starting with $y = \frac{1000}{x}$, and I've just been staring at Desmos for a while messing with values, but I can't seem to find any meaningful numbers. I came across the golden ratio at some point, but I do not know how that fits in. How would I go about finding this equation?

Comment: A curve has a $y$ intercept at point $(0,b)$ only when that point is on the curve. But your equation, after multiplying by $x,$ is $xy=1000,$ and if $(0,b)$ satisfied that one would get $0 \cdot b=1000$ which is false.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Maybe if you explain the purpose behind all of this, it may be a little clearer how to help you.

Comment: @DavidK This equation would let me calculate the impact on a preexisting score (represented by x) from 0-100, impacting it as +50 when the score is at a minimum (x = 0) and less as the score approaches 100, finishing at (100, 0), meaning no change when the score is already 100. It's for a popularity algorithm but now that I'm thinking about it, I realize that has a ton of flaws haha. Maybe 50 should be more like 5.

Comment: So if $x$ is the popularity score of something at some point in time, $0\leq x\leq100,$ then you get some new information (it's not clear what) and the popularity score will change to $x+\Delta.$ You're trying to figure out what $\Delta$ should be, right? So you have to ask what makes a useful "popularity" score and what makes a useless one. As you hinted, relatively large changes in the score based on just a little new information is usually not helpful. But there are other things to be concerned about as well.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Chamomile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of $(x-a)(y-b)=1$ is a hyperbola. You can solve a couple of equations to find values of $a$ and $b$ so it goes through $(0,50)$ and $(100,0)$.  If I did my algebra/arithmetic right, $a=(100\pm\sqrt{10008})/2$ and $b=(50a+1)/a$.

Comment: Note: $a$ is very close to $-1/50$, and $b$ is very close to $-1/100$.

Comment: If you prefer whole numbers, then $(x+100)(y+50)=10000$ works nicely.

Comment: You know what, (x + 100)(y + 50) = 10000 actually works very well for me. I will do a little tweaking to the steepness of the curve, but that seems to be the way to go that I was looking for. Thank you! P.S. Apologies for the lack of LaTeX - I’m writing this from my phone.